# MPI_Bcast all processes sends to all the rest of process

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to make that  every process broadcasts to all the rest of processes  this way

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{

  int MyProc, size,tag=1;
  int msg_recpt;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyProc);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  printf("Process # %d started \n", MyProc);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    MPI_Bcast( &MyProc, 1, MPI_INT, MyProc, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Recv(&msg_recpt, 1, MPI_CHAR, MyProc, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Proc #%d recv'd message from Proc #%d \n", MyProc, msg_recpt) ;


  printf("Finishing proc %d\n", MyProc);

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I need to show the sender process on the message after `MPI_Recv` but I think it's blocked the execution doesn't arrive to `printf("Finishing proc %d\n", MyProc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation. All MPI task in the communicator must invoke it with a matching signature (e.g. count and datatype) and they must all use the same `root` task.

Your code might block in `MPI_Bcast()` (since the message is very small, this is a bit unlikely, though you should not take that for granted). And if it does not, it will definitely block in `MPI_Recv()` since there is no matching send operation.

Collective and Point-to-point operations are independent in MPI.

You either need a loop of `MPI_Bcast()` or if you have enough memory to receive the messages of all the ranks, you can use `MPI_Alltoallv()` once.